# MYSQL Group Most recent by date

Tags: mysql, database

I'm re-asking this question because most of the examples have some strange table joining that doesn't make sense to me. What I'm trying to do is pull the most recent mail by date (in Y-m-d format) yet group them by the date of the message.

```
$query = "
SELECT * 
  FROM mail 
 WHERE ( receiver = '$username' OR sender = '$username' ) 
GROUP 
    BY date DESC
";
```

This is what I have started with, but I need to pull the most recent value by date. Anyone know how this might be done but still retain the receiver and sender qualifiers?

Table structure: http://projecttranslation.org/cvlgbt/www/web/mail.pdf

Comment: I think this is an example of a ["group-wise maximum"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) which I believe would be a good search term to find more info about it.

Comment: side note: the brackets aren't needed. They're mostly used for subqueries, so you can safely delete them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query =
"SELECT * FROM mail m
    WHERE ( receiver = '$username' OR sender = '$username' )
    AND timestamp = ( select max(timestamp) from mail m2
                      WHERE ( receiver = '$username' OR sender = '$username' )
                      AND m.date = m2.date )";
```

Comment: I'm trying to get them to group up by date and then pull the most recent row from said date. `LIMIT 1` only pulls one row but I need to pull them all and group by date.

Comment: In that case you will need to identify what you mean by 'most recent row', do you have a time column as well as the date one? It would help if you listed all the columns on your mail table, since you will not get away with just using * once we start the sort of manipulation you are talking about.

Comment: I just added a link to my table structure

Comment: I've edited it, though N.B. my latest version will return multiple rows for a particular date if the most recent timestamp is ever duplicated. Also  it's pretty horrible, could do with a CTE to clean it up.

Comment: Sweet that worked! I just made a small tweak and added `ORDER BY date DESC` at the end so it sorted them with the newest at the top. Works perfect, thanks so much!

Comment: I've just edited it again, please do check it as I had messed it up fairly much.

Comment: I really do NOT understand and can't comprehend the m1 m2, whatever that is junk.

Comment: I read up on group-wise-maxiumum and such but it doesn't explain it very well.

Comment: They're just aliases because the same table is used twice in the SQL statement. Removes ambiguity.

Comment: So I just discovered that I need to re-work this query yet again because I have to change how I pull the data. I was set on date, but I think what I actually want to do is make the mail system "thread-like". So I need to sort the mail messages into usernames whether it's sender or receiver it should go in the same thread if it's the same two users talking. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Hi, you really need to create a new question if you have a new requirement - this one needs to stay as it is, or the answers won't match it.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want the row(s) from the most recent date.  *This is not an aggregation query!*  This is filtering:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM mail m
WHERE ? IN (m.receiver, m.sender) AND
      date = (SELECT MAX(m2.date)
              FROM mail m2
              WHERE (m2.receiver = m.sender AND m2.sender = ?) OR
                    (m2.sender = m.receiver AND m2.receiver = ?)
             );
```

Notice that I changed `'$username'` to a proper placeholder for a parameter (`?`).  Your version looks dangerously close to munging the query string with a string value -- which opens the query to SQL injection and can introduce really hard to debug syntax errors.

Comment: I wish I understood what was going on in this code you posted.

Comment: @MatthewWalker . . . It is using a correlated subquery.  You can learn about them in the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/correlated-subqueries.html.

Comment: we can't be 100% sure if they're using a prepared statement or not.